# Disable untyped imports

Tags: typescript, import

Previous versions of TypeScript would prevent you from importing modules that lacked typing (via a `.d.ts` file or `@types/`).  Newer versions allow the imports by typing them all as `any`.  **Is it possible to disable this behavior?**

I'd like to enforce at least *some* sort of typing on all packages being used.

Comment: Did you set `noImplicitAny` flag in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Saravana That was my initial thought.  Unfortunately this is an existing project with *many* implicit anys throughout the codebase.  Cutting those out would be a prohibitive amount of work - making sure that no one imports any untyped libraries?  A little more approachable.